# Dropping selected rows in Pandas with duplicated columns

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe like this:

```
fname    lname     email

Joe      Aaron   
Joe      Aaron     some@some.com
Bill     Smith 
Bill     Smith
Bill     Smith     some2@some.com
```

Is there a terse and convenient way to drop rows where {fname, lname} is duplicated and email is blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first check whether your "empty" data is `NaN` or empty strings. If they are a mixture, you may need to modify the below logic.

#### If empty rows are NaN

Using [`pd.DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and [`pd.DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = df.sort_values('email')\
       .drop_duplicates(['fname', 'lname'])
```

#### If empty rows are strings

If your empty rows are strings, you need to specify `ascending=False` when sorting:

```
df = df.sort_values('email', ascending=False)\
       .drop_duplicates(['fname', 'lname'])
```

#### Result

```
print(df)

  fname  lname           email
4  Bill  Smith  some2@some.com
1   Joe  Aaron   some@some.com
```

Comment: When I ran this code, the remaining record had a blank email.

Comment: This one worked for me:  df = df.sort_values('email', ascending=False)\
       .drop_duplicates(['fname', 'lname'])

Comment: @MarkGinsburg, That's interesting. It worked without specifying `ascending` for me.

Comment: version issue?  I'm on Python 2.7

Comment: @MarkGinsburg, I've updated, think this might be the issue.

Comment: Yes they were strings

Answer (score 0):

You can using `first` with `groupby` (Notice replace empty with np.nan, since the `first` will return the first **not null** value for each columns)

```
df.replace('',np.nan).groupby(['fname','lname']).first().reset_index()
Out[20]: 
  fname  lname           email
0  Bill  Smith  some2@some.com
1   Joe  Aaron   some@some.com
```